# grep not showing unprintable delimiterin

Tags: regex, grep

I am having some problems trying to grep from a file:

`grep "1234" file.txt`

The result shows:
...123456=789=....

But the output should be:
...1234.56=7.89=...

I know there is a hidden delimiter \001 and I need to display it but don't know how. I tried 
`grep -P $"'\001'|1234"  file.txt` but with no luck.

Thank you for your help. JS

Comment: So, a non-printable character does not show up on the terminal? Sounds about right.

Comment: not sure what you are expecting, but pipe it to `cat -v` ? for ex: `printf 'a\001b\n' | cat -v`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the non printable characters you need to pass the file through cat with v option.
you can either try

```
grep "1234" file.txt |cat -v
```

or

```
cat -v file.txt | grep "1234"
```